# HTML + CSS - Picture is strangely streched everywhere, except Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

I have a strange problem with my frontend HTML + CSS code. 
A centered image is strangely stretched everywhere - Chrome, Safari, IE others.. except Firefox.
Down are some images of it and code. I'm new in frontend programming, so IDK what to do. It should also be fully responsive. What's wrong?

Thank for any tips :)

**Firefox:**
[image: Firefox]
**Others:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="botstyle.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CrazyBot Home</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkForm()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('input').value == 'hello'){
            window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
            alert('Correct Password!');

        }else {
            alert('Wrong Password!');
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="container">
        <img src="assets/bot1.png" alt="lol">
        <p style="text-align: center">

        <div class="Wrapper">

            <div class="Input">
                <span>Enter closed beta access code:</span>
                <form method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(); return true;">
                    <input type="text" id="input" class="Input-text" placeholder="Beta code">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </p>
        </p>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image: url("assets/background1.jpg");
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.container {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 275px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img has to be made responsive in your css stylesheet.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the following css to the image and see if it gets solved else please upload a working demo, so that we can help you better.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```